# regular expression group and sum

Tags: regex

Regex gurus,

I don't use regex regularly, sorry if this is a newbie question.

I have these sample strings:

1. "I have 10 cars & 12 trucks"
2. "We own 2 cars & 1 truck"
3. "2 cars & 2 trucks."
4. "1 car"
5. "1 truck"
6. "2 cars"
7. "2 trucks"
8. "We have 1 pickup . Another 2 cars & 1 truck."
9. "Bought 3 sedans. Another 10 trucks  & 10 cars"

I need this output:

```
   car  truck
1. 10   12
2. 2    1
3. 2    2
4. 1    0
5. 0    1
6. 2    0
7. 0    2
8. 2    2   (Ford pickup is a type of truck)
9. 13   10   (sedans is a type of car)
```

The numbers can be any integer. Can it be done in one regex? 
If not, in my case, it's OK to do multiple passes. Language is not important, I am more interested in the regex pattern/s.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex alone can't do this. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: You'd have to use something like `(\d+) (\w+)` and write some code to decide if it's a car or a truck and do the calculations.

Comment: Regex can't "create" characters. I'm especially referring to the `0` in your desired output for a "not found" number. You need some code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with a programming language, you can do:

```
(?:(\d+)\s+(?:\bsedans?\b|\bcars?\b))|(?:(\d+)\s+(?:\bpickups?\b|\btrucks?\b))
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/3c0GIK/1)

Here is a Perl script to demonstrate:

```
$ txt='"I have 10 cars & 12 trucks"
> "We own 2 cars & 1 truck"
> "2 cars & 2 trucks."
> "1 car"
> "1 truck"
> "2 cars"
> "2 trucks"
> "We have 1 pickup . Another 2 cars & 1 truck."
> "Bought 3 sedans. Another 10 trucks & 10 cars"'

$ echo "$txt" | perl -lne 'BEGIN{print "\tCars\tTrucks"}
                         $c+=$1 while(/(?:(\d+)\s+(?:\bsedans?\b|\bcars?\b))/g);
                         $t+=$1 while(/(?:(\d+)\s+(?:\bpickups?\b|\btrucks?\b))/g);
                         printf "%i\t%3i\t%10i\t%s\n", ++$i,$c,$t, $_;
                         $c=0; $t=0;'
```

Prints:

```
    Cars    Trucks
1    10         12  "I have 10 cars & 12 trucks"
2     2          1  "We own 2 cars & 1 truck"
3     2          2  "2 cars & 2 trucks."
4     1          0  "1 car"
5     0          1  "1 truck"
6     2          0  "2 cars"
7     0          2  "2 trucks"
8     2          2  "We have 1 pickup . Another 2 cars & 1 truck."
9    13         10  "Bought 3 sedans. Another 10 trucks & 10 cars"
```

Comment: Great answer and you go above and beyond. I am actually doing this in R and I am able to modify the expression and apply to the rest of my dataset. Good job and thank you!